# How to open file from server with python?

Tags: python, ssh-tunnel

I need to access and open a file on a server with python. I have a Centos server which I can access from **terminal** with `ssh root@172.24.2.233` and enter the user password.

**Question** 
If I have a file on the server in this path: `/var/document.txt` what do I write to access that path and open the `document.txt` on my local machine?

If the file was on my local machine, I could read it with this:

```
import glob

# for example if i want to see file in the folder
for f in glob.glob('/var/*.*'):
    print(f) # output --> document.txt
    # read file
    read = open(f, 'r')
```

How do I access the file if it is on the server?
I do not want to download the file, edit it and upload it again.

Comment: Is python installed on the remote server?

Comment: You will have to download the file and process it if you want to process the file on the local machine

Comment: @bigbounty nope, on my local machine but i want to read file that on the server.

Comment: Try looking into sshfs, to either mount the remote file system on your local machine, or second option, download the file from server to your local machine, and then run the script here, or third option, upload the script to server and run the script there.

Comment: Might be helpful: https://pypi.org/project/scp/

Comment: thank you very much everyone, i will looking on it.

Answer (score 1):

```
from contextlib     import closing
from fabric.network import connect
user = 'root' # your SSH user
host = '172.24.2.233' #IP of your server
port = '22' #SSH Port
remote_file = '/var/document.txt'
with closing(connect(user, host, port)) as ssh, \
     closing(ssh.open_sftp()) as sftp, \
     closing(sftp.open(remote_file)) as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line)
```

Comment: thank you for response, i think this is what i looking for but now i have some error like this `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fabric.network'` despite having already installed the fabric with this command `pip install fabric` and now my fabric version is `fabric 2.5.0`, so what is a problem?

Comment: Are you using a virtual enviroment (venv)? Maybe you did not install it in the venv but on the system wide installation. What python version are you using?

Comment: Python 3.8.2, and yes i did not install it in the venv.

Comment: but you are using a venv? If so, use the venv and install it there. Then it should work.

Comment: @Kaow, why don't you use directly scp ? Meaning  from local machine instead of ssh , do `scp root@172.24.2.233:/var/document.txt .` and you'l have the file directly on you machine in the directory from which you launched the scp command (scp uses the SSH protocol to copy files across system by extending the syntax of cp.)

Comment: @dejdej Because the file that i want to read is a traffic log of the server and the content will alway changing, that why i want to read it directly instead of transfer the file from server to the local machine.

Comment: This is an *incorrect* answer, as you are trying to pass the password as a port in the function call.