# How to read file from server using python

Tags: python, server, sftp, fabric

I want to read a json file from my server:103.227.176.29 but got an error"**invalid literal for int() with base 10: '103.227.176.29**" and I don't know how to fix it.
What can I do to fix this problem?

```
from contextlib     import closing
from fabric.network import connect
user = 'cortekr1_cuong' 
password = '12345678'
host = '103.227.176.29' 
port = '3306' 
remote_file = '/RBICloudv1/static/json/vietnamprovince/vn.json'
with closing(connect(user, password, host, port)) as ssh, \
     closing(ssh.open_sftp()) as sftp, \
     closing(sftp.open(remote_file)) as file:
    for line in file:
      print(line)
```

Comment: This post will answer your question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62850543/how-to-open-file-from-server-with-python

Comment: Post the traceback. We shouldn't have to guess where the error is.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Password is not a parameter, so you're trying to pass the host as the port, which it's not a number

https://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.12.1/api/core/network.html#fabric.network.connect

By the way, port 3306 is commonly used for mysql, not an sftp server